# SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure multiple SELECTS returned as one set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, multiple-resultsets

I'd like to write a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure which returns in one record:

- Max Stock price for the year,
- Min Stock price for the year,
- Max Stock price for the month,
- Min Stock price for the month

Reviewing previous posts I've tried `select#1 UNION ALL select#2` but this returns two result rows(regardless of AS) of two columns rather than one row of four columns. (I'm a noob and thus not completely sure this is a problem that can't be parsed by the webserver or webpage -- my coder has said one row is preferable -- so advice in that regard is great too).

Temporary tables and a new 2012 feature also seem possible but is there an easier way that I am missing?

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: `UNION ALL` returns only 1 result set, not two. It could return 2 rows however. Sounds like you want a single row with 4 columns?

Comment: Can you please show the SQL with 'union all'? I'd expect such one to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided table definitions but....

```
SELECT 
MIN(StockPrice) MinYr, 
MAX(StockPrice) MaxYr, 
MIN(
    CASE 
       WHEN MONTH(ADate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
       THEN StockPrice 
       ELSE NULL 
    END
) MinMth, 
MAX(
    CASE 
       WHEN MONTH(ADate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
       THEN StockPrice 
       ELSE NULL 
    END
) MaxMth
FROM Table
WHERE YEAR(ADate) = Year(GETDATE())
```

This is not necessarily the best SQL for performance (as there are functions around columns). It is the simplest code though.